# Using bit mask to convert a signed integer into two's complement

Tags: c

I am given this code to convert a signed integer into two's complement but I don't understand how it really works, especially if the input is negative.

```
void convertB2T( int32_t num) {

    uint8_t bInt[32];
    int32_t mask = 0x01;
    for (int position = 0; position < NUM_BITS; position++) {
        bInt[position] = ( num & Mask) ? 1 : 0;        
        Mask = Mask << 1;
    }
}
```

So my questions are:

1. num is an integer, Mask is a hex, so how does num & Mask work? Does C just convert num to binary representation and do the bitwise and? Also the output of Mask is an integer correct? So if this output is non-zero, it is treated as TRUE and if zero, FALSE, right?
2. How does this work if num is negative? I tried running the code and actually did not get a correct answer (all higher level bits are 1's).

Comment: *mask is a hex*. No, `mask` and `num` have the same type, `int32_t`. Hexadecimal is just a representation. So decimal 16 and hex A are the same value. What is the function meant to do? It's kind of useless anyway since it doesn't return anything. You'd also better hope that `NUM_BITS` is not larger than 32 or you have a buffer overrun.

Comment: @user90593 "How does this work if num is negative? I tried running the code and actually did not get a correct answer (all higher level bits are 1's)"

That sounds correct for two's complement.

Comment: `hex` and `decimal` are understandable for human. Machine understands only 0's and 1's.

Comment: @niko assuming that the machine is binary which it need not be

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'm supposed to call convertB2T(num) in main(). NUM_BITs is defined to be 32; I just didn't include it in the question.

Comment: You haven't said what the function is meant to do. As it stands it is useless. If you use NUM_BITS for thee array length, use it for the loop too. Try to work out what the function is meant to do and explain that in the question.

Comment: For this code to successfully "convert a signed integer into two's complement", it depends on the the underlying `int32_t` representation is all ready 2's complement.  This is a very _reasonable_ assumption, but it is an assumption.  A better function would _arithmetically_ tear apart `num` to derive the two's complement representation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This program basically extracts each bit of the number and puts it in a vector. So every bit becomes a vector element. It has nothing to do with two's complement conversion (although the resulting bit-vector will be in two's complement, as the internal representation of numbers is in two's complement).

1. The computer has no idea what hex means. Every value is stored in binary, because binary is the only thing computer understands. So, ,the "integer" and the hex values are converted to binary (the hex there is also an integer). On these binary representations that the computer uses, the binary operators are applied.
2. In order to understand what is happening with the result when num is negative, you need to understand that the result is basically the two's complement representation of num and you need to know how the two's complement representation works. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) is a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions

1.Yes num is integer represented in `decimal` format  and mask is also integer represented in `hex` format.
Yes C compiler treats `num` and `mask` with their binary equivalents.

Say

```
num = 24; // binary value on 32 bit machine is 000000000000000000011000
mask = 0x01; // binary value on 32 bit machine is 000000000000000000000001
```

Yes compiler now performs `&` bitwise and the equivalent binary values.

Yes if output is nonzero, treated as true

2. If a number is negative, its represented in 2's complement form.

Basically your code is just storing binary equivalent of number into `array`. You are not representing in twos complement.

If MSB is 1 indicates number is negative. if a number is negative

```
num = -24; // represent binary value of 24 
000000000000000000011000 -> apply 1's complement + 1 to this binary value

 111111111111111111100111 -> 1's complement
+000000000000000000000001 -> add 1
 ------------------------
 111111111111111111101000 -> -24 representation
 ------------------------
```